# Triangular Rasterisation with Barycentric Coordinates

Tags: graphics

I'm having trouble with a pretty basic function that tests whether or not a point is inside of the triangle by trying to find its barycentric points with 2 other points on the triangle. When i run my code my entire triangle fills up, but I'm also getting a fair amount of false positives. If I remove the boundbox condition I get 2 triangles reflected over imaginary line:

```
 bool insideTriangle(int point_test[2], int point_a[2], int point_b[2], int point_c[2]) 
{   //test-A = P-V1
    //test-B = P-V2
    int testMinusA[] = { point_test[0] - point_a[0],point_test[1] - point_a[1] };
    int testMinusB[] = { point_test[0] - point_b[0],point_test[1] - point_b[1] };
    float den = determinant(point_a, point_b);

    //s = determinant(P - V1, V2) / determinant(V1, V2)
    //t = determinant(V1, P - V2) / determinant(V1, V2)
    float s = determinant(testMinusA, point_b)/den;
    float t = determinant(point_a, testMinusB)/den;

    //if abs s >= 0 t>=0 and s+t < 1 then we good
    if ((s>=0 && t>= 0 && (s+t) < 1)||(s<=0 && t<=0 and (s+t)>-1)) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}

float determinant(int point_a[2], int point_b[2]) 
{
    return( point_a[0] * point_b[1]) - (point_b[0] *point_a[1]);
}
```

So ultimately I think my question is, Are my errors caused by some misunderstanding of barycentric(ity?) based on what you can see

Note: I'm following tiny renderers tutorial, if that helps educating me in any way.